# How to check for strings that starts with, and ends with my parameters

Tags: python, string

I have this function `matcher(word, first, last)`, where first will be the startswith(), and last will be endswith(). Word is obviously, the word I'm passing as argument.

It returns substrings from the word that has `first` as the first letter, and `last` as the last letter. For example,

```
matcher("apple", "a", "p")
>>> "app", "ap"
```

Is it possible to do it using the startswith() and endswith() built-in function? How should I approach this?

Comment: Your question says you already have your function, so just call the function

Comment: If you have a working function, post it. I do not get your results, should it not be apple why just app?

Comment: Can you paste your function definition, the values of `apple`, `a`, and `p`, as well as posting the problem you are facing? SO is not a code writing service, we will help you with the problems you may face, however.

Comment: I feel like there are some quotes missing from your code.  Shouldn't it say something like: `matcher("apple", "a", "p")`?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the `str.startswith` method and the `str.endswith` method into a nested `for` loop:

```
def matcher(word, first, last):
    length = len(word)
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i + 1, length + 1):
            sub = word[i:j]
            if sub.startswith(first) and sub.endswith(last):
                print(sub)

matcher("apple", 'a', 'p')
```

Output:

```
ap
app
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic for how I would do it:

1. Create a list to store these substrings
2. Traverse the string till you find the first instance of the start letter
3. Keep storing letters from here in a result string till you come across the end letter, at which point append this substring to the list and go on. Do not reset the result string for there may be longer strings.
4. If you come across the start letter again, call the matcher function again, but only on the remaining letters (recursive). Whatever it returns, merge with your current list.
5. When you have traversed the entire string, return the list

This way you run the function once for every instance of the start letter.